# HTML Table Column after Column

Tags: html

Is it possible to write the first column in a table in HTML and then the next column? If you write it like this:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test4</td>
        <td>Test5</td>
        <td>Test6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test7</td>
        <td>Test8</td>
        <td>Test9</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

You just write the first row and then the second row. But I want to write the first column first. Is this possible?

Edit: 
I have 5 Arrays with different sizes. They all include Strings.

Array1[2]: "Thomas", "Jon"

Array2[3]: "Bob", "Karl", "Jake"

Array3[4]: "Stephan", "Barack", "Steve", "Nicole"

Array3[1]: "Robert"

Array5[4]: "Carla", "Carlos", "Niggel", "Cedric"

The Header of the Tables should include the workdays. At the end I will have a Table with 5 Rows and some columns. To create this table I need to write the first Columne with a Loop for the 1. Array. Then a second Column for the second Array and so on. Right?
Do you have another idea how to write this table? I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802510/display-only-certain-columns-in-a-table

Comment: This is how you structure a `<table>` element. Why do you want to write columns first.? If it's for styling, there are other ways to do it

Comment: it's unclear what you want to ask. This is normal and expected behavior. You nest columns inside rows, what's the problem?

Comment: So all array have same no of elements?

Comment: Can you please provide proper array with data. It's easier to fix your problem!

Comment: They all have less then 10 String in them. But Array1 could have 4 Strings and Array2 could have 8 Strings.

Comment: var array1 = ['R1C1', 'R2C1', 'R3C1'];
var array2 = ['R1C2', 'R2C2', 'R3C2'];
var array3 = ['R1C3', 'R2C3', 'R3C3'];
var array4 = ['R1C4', 'R2C4', 'R3C4'];

Comment: Is it ok that format I provided above?

Comment: Yes, thats right. :)

Comment: ok let me do a fiddle for you

Comment: Ty, that would be nice :)

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Render the table by rows and then use javascript to invert the table.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwdLj/49/)

```
$("a").click(function () {
$("table").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newrows = [];
    $this.find("tr").each(function () {
        var i = 0;
        $(this).find("td,th").each(function () {
            i++;
            if (newrows[i] === undefined) {
                newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>");
            }
            newrows[i].append($(this));
        });
    });
    $this.find("tr").remove();
    $.each(newrows, function () {
        $this.append(this);
    });
});

return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how the HTML standard is. You make your table, then you make a row, and then your columns. There is some additional stuff for headers, bodies, etc. But the standard (and only supported method) is by row and not by column.

**NOTE:** Anyways if you have any specific reason to do like that then please explain your scenario and we will help you to make this working in a correct approach.

Comment: Hey :) I tried to descripe my Problem. I hope you understand it :)

Comment: Yes but that you can do by row and then column. Is there any issue doing that or any specific reason to do that in reverse order.

Comment: OK, that will help us.

Comment: I probably don't have the knowledge to do this row by row. With column by column you just need to create 1 Loop.